# Why is my Scaling-Pixelated(no interpolation/antialiasing) Algorithm Slow? Optimization?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, pixelate

I've decided to get serious about web design, mainly focusing on client side for now. I have been working on some designs incorporating low res images and scaling up to get a pixelated look. The problem is I keep running into variable quality when testing under different browsers and different machines. So far I have discovered 2 fairly simple ways(see below) to get a pixelated result, that work 90% of the time: one by modifying css properties, and another by changing canvas context variables in js. Both these solutions produce crisp-edge pixelation in the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, and Vivaldi; although, upon testing on an older computer of mine, I had variable levels of blurriness, testing on different browsers. Upon further searching, I came up with a third solution(see below) involving calling ImageData() on a canvas context, and applying that data to a new image and then drawing that image to the canvas and rescaling. This solution does the best at creating a crisp image in all my tests. The problem is that my algorithm is ~100x slower to run than the first 2 solutions. This fraction of second is hardly noticeable, although I see this perhaps causing problems when trying to design a responsive web app. Is there a way to make my algorithm faster? Or should to give up on supporting old machines and alt browsers?

1. CSS solution

   ```
   <html>
       <head>
           <title>css image-rendering...</title>
           <style>
               #myimg {
                   image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             /* STOP SMOOTHING, GIVE ME SPEED  */
                   image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox                        */
                   image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* Opera                          */
                   image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Chrome (and eventually Safari) */
                   image-rendering: pixelated;                 /* Chrome */
                   image-rendering: optimize-contrast;         /* CSS3 Proposed                  */
                   -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE8+                           */
               }
           </style>
       </head>
       <body>
           <img id="myimg"/>
       </body>
       <script>
           var imgin = new Image();
           imgin.src = "./bill64.png";
           var imgframe = document.getElementById("myimg");
           imgin.onload = function(){
               var magnfctn = 16; //magnify by this
               imgframe.width = imgin.width*magnfctn;
               imgframe.height = imgin.height*magnfctn;
               imgframe.src = "./bill64.png";
           }
       </script>
   </html>
   ```

[image]

2. ImageSmoothingEnabled=false

   ```
   <html>
       <head>
           <title>ImageSmoothingEnabled=false</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <canvas width="256" height="256" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
       </body>
       <script>
           var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
           var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
           var imgin = new Image();
           imgin.src = "./pig64.png";
           imgin.onload = function(){//**Edit: Thanks Kaiido, performance slightly improved**
               var magnfctn = 16; //magnify by this
               //ctx.drawImage(imgin, 0, 0);
               //var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, imgin.width, imgin.height);
               c.width = imgin.width*magnfctn;
               c.height = imgin.height*magnfctn;
               ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
               ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
               ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
               ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
               ctx.scale(magnfctn,magnfctn);
               //ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
               ctx.drawImage(imgin, 0, 0);
           }
       </script>
   </html>
   ```

[image]

3. Custom JavaScript

   ```
   <html>
       <head>
           <title>No Interpol...</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <canvas width="256" height="256" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
       </body>
       <script>
           var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
           var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
           var imgin = new Image();
           imgin.src = "./macaque64.png";
           imgin.onload = function(){
               var magnfctn = 16; //magnify by this
               ctx.drawImage(imgin, 0, 0);
               var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, imgin.width, imgin.height);
               var largeData = ctx.createImageData(imgin.width*magnfctn, imgin.height*magnfctn);
               for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4) {
                   for(var x=0;x<magnfctn;x++){
                       for(var y=0;y<magnfctn;y++){
                           largeData.data[magnfctn*i+4*x +
                                          magnfctn*imgin.width*4*y +
                                          4*imgin.width*magnfctn*(magnfctn-1)*Math.floor(i/4/imgin.width)] =
                                          imgData.data[i];//red
                           largeData.data[magnfctn*i+4*x +
                                          magnfctn*imgin.width*4*y +
                                          1+4*imgin.width*magnfctn*(magnfctn-1)*Math.floor(i/4/imgin.width)] =
                                          imgData.data[i+1];//green
                           largeData.data[magnfctn*i+4*x +
                                          magnfctn*imgin.width*4*y +
                                          2+4*imgin.width*magnfctn*(magnfctn-1)*Math.floor(i/4/imgin.width)] =
                                          imgData.data[i+2];//blue
                           largeData.data[magnfctn*i+4*x +
                                          magnfctn*imgin.width*4*y +
                                          3+4*imgin.width*magnfctn*(magnfctn-1)*Math.floor(i/4/imgin.width)] =
                                          imgData.data[i+3];//alpha
                       }
                   }
               }
               c.width = imgin.width*magnfctn;
               c.height = imgin.height*magnfctn;
               ctx.putImageData(largeData, 0, 0);
           }
       </script>
   </html>
   ```

[image]

*Note*(cross-origin issue):
Some browsers require disabling security to process local files.

FireFox:
works by default

Safari:
First you need to enable the develop menu.
Click on the Develop menu
Select Disable Local File Restrictions.

Chrome:
terminal: "open -a "Google Chrome" --args --allow-file-access-from-files"

Opera: 
terminal: "open -a Opera --args --allow-file-access-from-files"

Vivaldi:
terminal: "open -a Vivaldi --args --allow-file-access-from-files"

Comment: Also noteworthy: The CSS solution does not produce crisp pdf's when printing the page(safari 11.0, chrome 65.0, firefox, 46.0). https://imgur.com/gallery/VjxADQY

Comment: test input.png's: https://imgur.com/gallery/h2pkYvZ

Comment: The best would probably be a fallback strategy: check if CSS is supported, otherwise check if `imageSmoothingEnabled`, otherwise, use `getImageData`. Note that in your imageSmoothingEnbaled, you absolutely don't need getImageData, and hence can also treat cross-origin images: https://jsfiddle.net/rpLnbvks/

Comment: Have you considered using webworkers? They can compute all not immedeately needed images in background.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Tschallacka! I'm already looking into it...